# null reference exception array 2d

Tags: c#, function, multidimensional-array, nullreferenceexception

ive got this class it has one 2dArray and when im trying to fill it im getting the error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AdminGrid.FullNot(Int32 Row, Int32 Column, Int32 Full, System.String PieceName)

```
public class AdminGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public int numRows;
    public int numColumns;
    private int[,] ArrayGrid;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Init() {
                numColumns = 6;
                numRows = 6;
        ArrayGrid = new int[numRows,numColumns];

        for(int y = 0;y < numRows;y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0;x < numColumns;x++)
            {
                ArrayGrid[y,x] = 0; 
            }
        }
    }

    public void FullNot(int Row,int Column,int Full,string PieceName)
    {   
        ArrayGrid[Row,Column] = 1;//Error is here
    }

    public int WhatsonGrid(int Row,int Col)
    {
        return ArrayGrid[Row,Col];
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? as you can see my array is filled with 0s i thought that would fix this but it seems like not,also i made sure the values are inside the array meaning the max for columns and rows are 5,5

im using the engine Unity  so Init //actually called start

it gets called when the game starts as a rule thats why im pretty sure it is called

Comment: Where you call FullNot method, please add that code

Comment: Did you call Init at any point?

Comment: Are you calling `FullNot` before calling `Init`?

Comment: @Makenshi - As others asked already - please post the code where you call `FullNot` and the few lines before (also where you call `Init`, if possible).

Comment: Sorry as i added im using the engine Unity so Init is called automatically so theres no doubt its being called or so i thought it seems it is just printing 2 values

Comment: Inside the `FullNot` method add `if(ArrayGrid == null) Init();` this should be the definitive test on the reason of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayGrid` is a reference-type field, so will be null by default, so I conclude simply: you haven't called `Init`. So: call `Init`.

Comment: init is called im pretty sure of it

Comment: @Makenshi where is it called? If I'd had been called, the array would be non-null. It is the not reference here; not really much doubt...

Comment: ok the error was Init was being called at the same time as another inits somehow and so it was filling the array with garbage sorry

Answer (score 1):

Rename Init with AdminGrid and all will be fine )

```
public AdminGrid()
{
...
}
```